# Reading sensor data from Wear OS wearables using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, wear-os, android-sensors, samsung-health

How can the sensor data and health data of a Wear OS wearable device (watch) be read by a Flutter android app on the iOS/android phone?

Additionally, is there a common API to access the sensor/health data for all Wear OS watches? Or does each brand (Google, Samsung, etc) have their own API to access the data?

Comment: What you are looking for is in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76464852/12555686

Answer (score 2):

you can use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/health

it returns data from google fit, health connect also works for ios devices.

[image: Check this image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Google Fit API** in your Flutter app to access the sensor data and health data from the connected Wear OS watch. The Google Fit API provides a set of classes and methods to retrieve various types of data, such as step count, heart rate, and activity data, from the connected device.

Regarding the second question, each brand may have its own API to access sensor and health data. However, the Google Fit API provides a common interface to access data from various devices and platforms, including Wear OS devices